# How do you replace a match, using regex, only if it is not preceded by a given character?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a foreach statement that is searching for a string value within a `List<string>`. If the current line being read contains the string, I want to replace it, but with certain caveats.

```
foreach (string shorthandValue in shorthandFound)
{
    if (currentLine.Contains(shorthandValue))
    {
        // This method creates the new string that will replace the old one.
        string replaceText = CreateReplaceString(shorthandValue);
        string pattern = @"(?<!_)" + shorthandValue;
        Regex.Replace(currentLine, pattern, replaceText);
        // currentline is the line being read by the StreamReader.
     }
}
```

I'm trying to get the system to ignore the string if the `shorthandValue` is preceded by an underscore character (`"_"`). Otherwise, I want it to be replaced (even if it is at the start of the line).

What am I not doing correctly?

**UPDATE**

This is working mostly correctly:

```
Regex.Replace(currentFile, "[^_]" + Regex.Escape(shorthandValue), replaceText);
```

However, while it does ignore the underscore, it it removing any space before the shorthandValue string. So if the line read "This is a test123.", and the "test123" is replaced, I end up with this result:

"This is aVALUEOFTHESHORTHAND."

Why is the space being removed?

**UPDATE AGAIN**

I changed the regex back to my `(?<!_)` and it is preserving the spaces.

Comment: I **do** find that info site very helpful but to play with (most) regex in a live setting, try regexpal.com for practice.

Comment: regular-expressions.info is excellent! I get a feeling you just don't want to put in the time. Also, the regex you tried makes me wonder if by any chance you're working on your DIPS application..?

Comment: It's not that I don't want to put in the time, I just haven't found that site to be that helpful in explaining things very clearly. I'm more of a book person, I guess. DIPS application? Not really sure what that is, so I don't think that's what I'm doing.

Comment: Are you throwing away the results of the Regex.Replace? ie maybe you just need `currentLine = Regex.Replace(currentLine, pattern, replaceText);`

Answer (score 4):

Your regex is correct. The problem is that Regex.Replace returns a new string.

You are ignoring the returned string.

Comment: It should be noted that this requires a single non-underscore *before* `shorthandValue` and would not work if `String.StartsWith(shorthandValue) == true`.

Comment: Your answer is what the OP already has, so I'm not sure what the correction was.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression looks correct, given you fix your code to actually save the string (hat tip to [@jameskyburz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14344301/7116)), so you should still ensure that `shorthandValue` is treated as a literal. To accomplish this use [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx):

```
var pattern = String.Format(@"(?<!_){0}", Regex.Escape(shorthandValue))
```